# How to run commands using variables which included quotes, in bash?

Tags: string, bash, shell, quotes

I'm trying to run a command while injecting a variable which has quotes, but bash keeps adding extra quotes which I don't need and falsifies the process...

this is my example:

```
set -x
MYVAR=" --name='user should login' "
cucumber $MYVAR
```

this results into running this:

```
cucumber  '--name='\''user' should 'login'\'''
```

and the command fails. However, when I run `cucumber --name='user should login'` as is, without using variables, everything goes as expected.

PS. same result with `cucumber "${MYVAR}"` or `cucumber "$MYVAR"`

Comment: `set -x;
MYVAR="--name=user should login";
cucumber "$MYVAR"`

Comment: This is [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to use BASH arrays for storing command lines:

```
myvar=(--name 'user should login')
cucumber "${myvar[@]}"
```

I've also lowercased your variable as using all UPPER case variables can be problematic sometimes.

Comment: Here, there is only 1 element in the array.

Comment: There is space between quotes which will do word splitting

Comment: `set -x; MYVAR="--name=user should login"; cucumber "$MYVAR" ` should work too...? But it's good to introduce OP to habit of using arrays for such use-cases... +1

Comment: `myvar=(--name='user should login')` resulted into `cucumber '--name=user should login'`, but using `myvar=(--name 'user should login')` did the job! thanks, you saved me a bunch of time

Comment: ^^ Oh, so there **are** 2 arguments. Then OP has no choice but move to arrays.

Comment: 'user should login' is the value of `name` argument. one could set it by mentioning after whitespace, or using equal sign

Comment: This answers only specific instance, not the general question.  That is, it wouldn't work if `cucumber` was replaced with another  command that _required_ the `=` after `--name`.

Comment: Using shell arrays to store command line it's a generic solution.

Comment: Example, swap `cucumber` with `mplayer` and swap `--name` with the `--playing-msg` option:   `myvar=(--playing-msg 'Hello World.') ; mplayer "${myvar[@]}" foo.avi; echo $?`

Answer (score -1):

This works, with no **bash**isms:

```
MYVAR=" --name='user should login' "
eval cucumber $MYVAR
```